# My CSS connected to my HTML isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

The aim of my project is to make a color palette maker and be able to save the palette. However, my squares in CSS aren't being connected. I checked the Dev Tools in Chrome, and when I clicked on the square div tag it didn't have any formatting.

MY HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Utility Page</title>
    <style src="styles.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <div class="square1"> </div>
    <div class="square2"> </div>
    <div class="square3"> </div>
        
    <button onclick="changeColor1()"> Change The Color </button>
    <button onclick="changeColor2()"> Change The Color </button>
    <button onclick="changeColor3()"> Change The Color </button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.square1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 122px;
}
.square2 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 122px;
}
.square3 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 122px;
}
```

JS CODE:

```
import Math
var colorValue = Array("#000000", "#000000", "#000000")
const hexademical = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D","E","F")

const function changeColor1() {
    document.querySelector(".square1").style.background = colorValue[0];
    colorValue[0] = colorDecide()
}
const function changeColor2() {
    

    document.querySelector(".square2").style.background = colorValue;
    colorValue[1] = colorDecide()
}
const function changeColor3() {

    document.querySelector(".square3").style.background = colorValue;
    colorValue[2] = colorDecide()
}


const function colorDecide() {
    let tempValue = "#"
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)
        tempValue = tempValue.concat(x)
    }
    return tempValue
}
```

The text editor I'm using is Sublime 3. Should I use the WebStorm IDE by JetBrains?

Comment: You're linking an "external" css file. You need to use a `link` tag. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

Comment: Advice: for these kind of questions, it's recommended to make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something. Then people can try out your code and make adjustments to them easily and help you solve your problem very easily.

Comment: @gitaarik a jsfiddle would be against the guidelines (questions must be self-containing). The stacksnippet is just fine. However, it would not solve the actual issue (same as a fiddle) on an incorrect link to a CSS file. Read the comment above! The OP doesn't declare a `rel`-attribute and used the wrong linking method (`src` instead of `href`)

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know. Stacksnippet is better indeed, I am not used to it yet haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're linking your `.css` file wrong. Here is how you should do it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
```

instead of

```html
<style src="styles.css"></style>
```

Comment: while this is correct you should comment on this as it has no value to SO and flag it accordingly. Answeri8ng just makes the auto-deletion process harder and longer. Questions that are purely based on typos or by not reading the basic manuals have no value for SO.